# Detailed quickly tutorial

Tags: application-development, quickly

Hi I kindly need a more detailed quickly tutorial that explain the python code./ For example, adding a login form to an application

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't tell us what you already found, I will just give a list of hopefully useful links:

[Quickly on the Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/)

[Python Gtk3](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

[Python Gtk2](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/)

[Acire Python snippets](http://aciresnippets.wordpress.com/)

Comment: ok thanx it helped alot

Comment: Could someone update the first link? It seems to point to developing for the Ubuntu phone now...

Answer (score 0):

Quickly seems to be dead project since 2012. No one mentions that anywhere except in some obscure bug reports.

Comment: Yeah, Quickly is outdated and replaced by Ubuntu Make and Snap. But also keep in mind that this question is already 5 years old so any new answer is probably irrelevant.

Comment: I have found this question because I have stepped on Quickly some time ago and looked for more info. If I did it I guess someone else would do the same hence info - not an answer - simply because nobody bothered to say it loud. If quickly had an note on its wiki it would be easy. I did not know about Make and Snap, and I was looking into Ubuntu SDK in the meantime, but even that seems to be abandoned, is not working either. Aside of all, M&S seems to be available from Ubuntu 16. I still run 14 so M&S is not an solution for me for the time being.